# Get all result not just the last one

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Hope you all are doing well. I have problem with for loop i want to get all result not just the last one.

```js
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
     var result = "";
     result += i;
}
console.log(result)
```

Can you please help me to resolve it. Thanks <3

Comment: What do you mean by `all result`?

Comment: When run code it give me 4, I want to get 1 2 3 4

Comment: try using let and move the result ="" outside loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using let and move the result ="" outside loop

```
let result="";

for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
     result += i;
}
console.log(result)
```